# Mount 2nd raid disk Ubuntu server

Tags: disk, raid

I have an Ubuntu server 18.04 and i'm trying to mount my second hard disk but nothing. I tried with **mount /dev/sdX /mnt** and **mount /dev/mdX /mnt** but without success.
Here some results

```
fdisk -l | grep "dev"
Disk /dev/sda: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
/dev/sda1          2048    1048575    1046528   511M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda2  *    1048576    2277375    1228800   600M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       2277376 2000408575 1998131200 952.8G fd Linux raid autodetect
Disk /dev/sdb: 953.9 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
/dev/sdb1          2048    1048575    1046528   511M 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb2  *    1048576    2277375    1228800   600M fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       2277376 2000408575 1998131200 952.8G fd Linux raid autodetect
Disk /dev/md0: 599 MiB, 628097024 bytes, 1226752 sectors
Disk /dev/md1: 952.7 GiB, 1022907908096 bytes, 1997867008 sectors

:~# lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 953.9G  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0   511M  0 part  [SWAP]
├─sda2    8:2    0   600M  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0   599M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sda3    8:3    0 952.8G  0 part  
  └─md1   9:1    0 952.7G  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0 953.9G  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0   511M  0 part  [SWAP]
├─sdb2    8:18   0   600M  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0   599M  0 raid1 /boot
└─sdb3    8:19   0 952.8G  0 part  
  └─md1   9:1    0 952.7G  0 raid1 /

:~# cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0 1000204632 sda
   8        1     523264 sda1
   8        2     614400 sda2
   8        3  999065600 sda3
   8       16 1000204632 sdb
   8       17     523264 sdb1
   8       18     614400 sdb2
   8       19  999065600 sdb3
   9        0     613376 md0
   9        1  998933504 md1

:~# cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      998933504 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 4/8 pages [16KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      613376 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
unused devices: <none>

:~# mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=b070be1c:fc22f459:25d3c18b:55a64573 name=51-159-213-140:0
ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.2 UUID=5a4a3ccb:1b82482b:41bd06d7:af65ecf3 name=51-159-213-140:1

:~# findmnt --real
findmnt: unrecognized option '--real'
Try 'findmnt --help' for more information.
```

I don't have graphical. Any help is welcome.

Comment: Does `cat /proc/mdstat` give any useful info on the state of the md arrays? Or perhaps `mdadm —examine —scan`?

Comment: What does "_without success_" mean? Did you get an error message? What was it. Did anything happen? If not, tell us. Please replace the references to `/dev/sdX` and `/dev/mdX` with the actual command(s) you used. Also, add the result of `findmnt --real` to your question

Comment: I don't see a second disk with partitions available to mount. Do you understand what RAID1 means?

Comment: `cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md1 : active raid1 sda3[0] sdb3[1]
      998933504 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      bitmap: 5/8 pages [20KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sda2[0] sdb2[1]
      613376 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
      
unused devices: <none>`
`:~# mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/0  metadata=1.2 UUID=b070be1c:fc22f459:25d3c18b:55a64573 name=51-159-213-140:0
ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.2 UUID=5a4a3ccb:1b82482b:41bd06d7:af65ecf3 name=51-159-213-140:1`
findmnt --real return nothing.

Comment: Add that to the question so that it's more readable and so that it doesn't get lost in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like both of your drives are already in use.

- RAID1 device `/dev/md0` is made up of `/dev/sda2` and `/dev/sdb2` and is mounted as `/boot`
- RAID1 device `/dev/md1` is made up of `/dev/sda3` and `/dev/sdb3` and is mounted as `/` (the root filesystem)

Comment: Ok i think i understand. So, how i find the free space partitions of the two disks ?

Comment: It doesn't look like there is any free space on either drive.  `fdisk -l` says both drives are 953.9 GB and they both have three partitions taking 511 MB (swap), 600 MB (/boot), and 952.8 GB (/) respectively.   What makes you think there's any unused/un-partitioned free space available?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I found it, thanks everyone for the help.